# 'WillPopScope' and 'PopScope' are not working when the Android back button is pressed

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router

I built an app that has a bottom navigation with go_router statefulshellbranches.

Screen are like:

Dashboard (container for bottom navigation)

```
Home

Updates

Profile
```

I had implemented two times back press for exiting the app by adding WillPopScope on top of Dashboard Screen scaffold (all the nested pages also contains there own scaffolds). It was working fine.

I have upgraded Flutter, and now I got to know that WillPopScope is deprecated.

I tried to use PopScope instead. But the onPopInvoked callback is not being called when I press back on an Android device. Then I again checked with WillPopScope, but onWillPop is also not being called.

Now I don’t know how can I debug this, I have tried logging messages inside *onWillPop* and *onPopInvoked*, but it is not logging and the app is exiting on the first back button press.

How can I fix this problem with PopScope migration?

Answer (score 3):

It is related to problems with go-router 13.x Just downgrade to latest 12.x and it will work (for my case at least).

Answer (score 1):

On page *[Android Predictive Back](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back)*, you can find the migration guide for WillPopScope. You have to notice that when `onPopInvoke` is called; it means your *app* will pop *for sure*! In order to handle if your app is eligible to pop or not, you have to use `canPop`. So, `onPopInvoke` is not sufficient alone to handle a pop, but it has to be used in combination with `canPop`.

On that page, you can find from simple migration cases to more advanced ones. Read carefully and good luck!